# Make project into exe that works without java installed

Tags: java

Right now im in a course in Agile development and at our demo it is an demand that
the project is an EXE and it should work without Java installed. 
I tried to talk to my teacher but he wont budge on the demand so is there anyway that i can make my project into and exe that can be executed without java installed.

sidenote: my last resort is to make an installer that force him to install java and then run the exe!

Comment: Jlink allows you to package java base modules in a custom runtime image. If you can go for Java 9, then that should solve your issue.

Comment: thanks i will check it out!

Comment: @aetheria i have tried Launch4j but the exe needs java